# Graph control, Data Virtualization in wp7 Mango

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, graph

I need to make graph control in WP7 Mango, but can't find anything suitable and free.Please help me to find control like in a second picture.I didn't find this control in silverlight toolkit.

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please take a look at this [post](http://www.silverlighthack.com/post/2010/10/08/Windows-Phone-7-RTM-Charting-using-the-Silverlight-Control-Toolkit.aspx). windows phone mango uses Siverlight 3, so you should still be able to use the charts from the silverlight toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Silverlight toolkit examples.](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) You can try port it to WP7 http://silverlight.codeplex.com/